# How to set bash next bash operation input equal to the output of the prvious operation?

Tags: linux, bash

I believe it is really easy, but I didn't find anywhere an answer for me. What I'm trying to do is:

```
echo file.war | sed s/.war// | rm -rf ???
```

to pass to the `rm -rf` the output of the sed command.

Not sure if it is the right way to get this...

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It would help if you described exactly what you're trying to do, since it's easy to interpret wrongly from code that doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: @legoscia, yeah, thanks. That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other possibilities, in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

- Use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

  ```
  rm -rf $(echo file.war | sed 's/\.war$//')
  ```
- Use a variable and [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

  ```
  file=file.war
  rm -rf "${file%.war}"
  ```
- Instead of the `echo | sed`, use a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) (and the command substitution):

  ```
  rm -rf $(sed 's/\.war$//' <<< "file.war")
  ```

This was in fact just to show you the command substitution `$(...)` thing (avoiding xargs that will fail miserably if you have file names containing funny symbols like spaces). Also to show you that in your case, `sed` is useless (thanks to the shell parameter expansion) and, if you really need `sed`, that the `echo | sed` thing can be avoided in `bash`.

I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve. I could imagine:

- you're trying to delete all files *file* such that *file.war* exist in current directory. In this case, I would do:

  ```
  for file in *.war; do
      rm -rf -- "${file%.war}"
  done
  ```
- You have a file called *filenames* that contains lines like:

  ```
  file1.war
  file2.war
  ...
  filen.war
  ```

  and you want to delete all files *file1*, *file2*, …, *filen*. Then I would do:

  ```
  while read -r file; do
      [[ ( $file = *.war ) && ( -f $file ) ]] || continue
      rm -rf -- "${file%.war}"
  done < filenames
  ```

Answer (score 3):

This is what 'xargs' does.

```
echo file.war | sed s/\.war$// | xargs rm -rf
```

And note my changes to your regex. It needs to be anchored and the '.' needs to be escaped.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. Work as a charm!

Comment: `\.` is changed by bash to `.`, which sed then treats as a “magic” character. To pass an escaped `.` to sed, you need to escape the backslash: `sed s/\\.war$//`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is

```
rm -rf `echo file.war | sed s/\.war$//`
```